# Converting Aspnet to aspnetcore: RequestContext.Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ok, so I'm working on converting a webApi from aspnet to aspnetcore.

I have the following inside of an HTTP post.

```
var name = ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
widget.CreatedBy = name;
//Other properties
DataContext.Widgets.Add(entity);
```

The problem I'm running into is that `RequestContext` doesn't seem to exist in `aspnetcore`.  I've been searching for the better part of a day for an equivalence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, from within a controller this is done like:

```cs
var claimsPrincipal = User;
```

Reference: [Migrate from ClaimsPrincipal.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current#retrieve-the-current-user-in-an-aspnet-core-app)

Comment: So far Im getting null for name this way, but i think its the right track.

Comment: For the `User.Name` property to be set, `ClaimType` used for the user name claim must match what your auth is setting it to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.claimsidentityoptions.usernameclaimtype

Comment: I suppose this answer is correct. I can plainly see the info i want on user.claims[9].  But im not having any luck updating the claimtype for name.  Ive tried numerous sites and sources and just gone down rabbit holes with no results.I suppose i'll just do a query on claims for "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" but that seems ugly.

Comment: @Seth You can just do `var name = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)`;